# Orientdb query approach to get properties of vertices and edges

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1, orientjs

Im a newbie to orient db .I have a vertex user which has properties adress,name and another vertex Images with properties imagename,date.Both are connected by and edge postedby.Now I want to write a query to select all images posted by a user with all the properties of both the vertices.How can I write the query to get this.I use orientjs in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var OrientDB = require('orientjs');
var db = OrientDB({
host: 'localhost',
port: 2424,
});
var db = db.use({
name: '<db name>',
username: '<username>',
password: '<pwd>'
});
db.query('select address, name, out("postedby").imagename as imagename, out("postedby").date as date from User where name = "<insert a name>" unwind imagename,date')
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
db.close();
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much Michela Bonizzi.Exacty what I wanted.Now I can kickstart my journey with Orientdb